# Unset/Set flag of object and persist changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am dealing with user objects. My service file:

```
angular.module('UserService',['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource){
    var User = $resource('/api/users/:id',
        { 
          list: { method: 'GET' },
          lock: { method: 'PATCH' }
        }
    );   
    return User;
});
```

The listing of users works well

```
<div ng:controller="UserController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <a ng:click="select(user)">
              {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the project file:

```
var app = angular.module('module-users', ['UserService']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: UserController, 
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('template_user_list')
    });
});


function UserController($scope, User){
    $scope.users = User.query();

    $scope.selectedUser = null;

    $scope.select = function(user){
        $scope.selectedUser = user;
    }

    $scope.lock = function(user){
        user.lock();
        console.log('lock user');
    }
}
```

However when I want to perform a user lock/unlock I get an error message that the method is unknown. Any ideas whats wrong? How can I perform a lock through the service? Any other suggestions?

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'lock'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) says:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions:Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
>
> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
>
> non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success],
>   [error])

Therefore in your case you should call `$lock` instead of `lock`

**UPDATE**

Spotted another problem in your code. Action parameters should be given as third parameter, not second. E.g.

```
var User = $resource('/api/users/:id',
        {}, //we have no default parameters
        { 
          list: { method: 'GET' },
          lock: { method: 'PATCH' }
        }
    );
```